# Google Sheets Apps Script: ID Token Not Generated When Called via Client-Side Function

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, google-cloud-functions, openid-connect

I have a Google Sheets Apps Script project.

**index.html** defines a sidebar the user opens which takes parameters `urlRange`, `xpathRange` & `outputCell` and passes them to `sendPayloadToCloudFunction` in **payload.gs** when the user calls `sendPayload` by clicking a button.

Within `sendPayloadToCloudFunction` in **payload.gs**, an ID Token is generated to be passed to the Google Cloud Function: `var idToken = ScriptApp.getIdentityToken();`

When `sendPayloadToCloudFunction` is invoked via the sidebar, the `urlRange`, `xpathRange` & `outputCell` arguments are logged in the browser console. The `idToken` argument should be logged, but is not. In addition, the Cloud Function logs display **Authorization is required to perform that action.**

If I run `sendPayloadToCloudFunction` in **payload.gs** from within the Apps Script editor (defining the required `urlRange`, `xpathRange` & `outputCell` parameters within the function, rather than being passed from `sendPayload` in **index.html**) then the ID Token is generated and the Cloud Function is invoked as expected with no authorization issues.

Why is the ID Token only generated when `sendPayloadToCloudFunction` is called via the Apps Script Editor, and not when called via the client-side `sendPayload` function in **index.html**?

How do I invoke `ScriptApp.getIdentityToken();` via the client-side sidebar such that the ID Token can be successfully passed to the Cloud Function along with the other parameters?

Answer (score 0):

This wasn't an issue with the code. This is a [known issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/69270374) which was resolved by logging out of other Google accounts.